# Need Help Interpreting the Imaginary Component of the Dot Product for Complex Valued Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I've been looking into a copy of Schaum's Outlines for linear algebra and came across the extension of the real-valued dot product into complex-valued vectors. For two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, $$ \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = u_1 \bar{v}_1 + u_2 \bar{v}_2 + \cdots + u_n \bar{v}_n $$
Where $\bar{v}_j$ is the complex conjugate of $v_j$.

I understand that using the conjugate of the second argument, $\vec{v}$ in this case, allows this definition to reduce to the real-valued dot product in the real case, and allows the real component, Re($\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$), to reflect the familiar idea of projecting and scaling two 'equivalent' vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$
(that is, if $ \vec{u}_\text{complex} =\: <2+4i,1+3i>,$ then the 'equivalent' real vector is $\vec{u}_\text{real}=\:<2,4,1,3>$).

This gives me a fine understanding for the real component of this complex dot product, but I can't find a similar familiarity for the imaginary component. I'm not sure exactly how to word my question as generally as I would like to, so for a concrete example:

Given two vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$, $\vec{z}=\:<5+2i,-3-7i,-6+8i>$ and $\vec{w}=\:<-9+2i,1+i,7-2i>$,$$\vec{z}\cdot\vec{w}=-109+12i$$$$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{z}=-109-12i$$

How can I interpret the numbers 12i and -12i? Is there a geometric interpretation (perhaps one relating to rotation?) that I can attribute to those values? Should I not be looking at the imaginary component alone? What does that number tell me, and what can I use it to do?

Another question to go with this: is the choice of taking the complex conjugate of the first argument as opposed to the second an agreed upon definition? Looking into this on my own, I've found many online sources disagree on which terms to take the conjugate of. The two definitions I'm seeing are:$$ \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = u_1 \bar{v}_1 + u_2 \bar{v}_2 + \cdots + u_n \bar{v}_n $$$$ \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \bar{u}_1 v_1 + \bar{u}_2 v_2 + \cdots + \bar{u}_n v_n $$Both of these definitions agree that $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \overline{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}}$, but they do give noticeably different results. Is one of these definitions preferable to the other? And, if so, why?

Using these definitions without understanding the justifications behind them really damages my ability to work with the material, so I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 1):

The imaginary part of the complex dot product is a [symplectic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space). I have never understood the significance of this, and I recommend that you don't worry about it. Because $\langle v, v \rangle = \| v \|^2$ is still real you can mostly ignore it in practice. The [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) guarantees that the inner product is just a convenient way to work with the norm (which is just an ordinary Euclidean norm); this is how I think about things anyway.

Comment: I also find it confusing at first.  Each element of the <z, w> inner product is a rotation.  So the inner product is an addition of rotations.  I'm not sure what useful properties that complex number has though.